# Mimic "Invoke" / "BeginInvoke" Style Method Call on Custom Class/Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I want to create a thread-safe method I can call from several workers without blocking the worker threads.  I also want the code to be decently brief much like the InvokeRequired->BeginInvoke type code is for UI Controls... of course I'm not using a `Control` in this case, the method is on a custom class.  I also don't necessarily want this for every method. So is this something that can be easily implemented on custom classes/methods?

Sudo Code:

```cs
class foo
{
    //Fields
    Context MyContext;
    List<T> UnsafeList = new List<T>();

    //Method
    public void MyMethod(int someArg, Item someOtherArg)
    {
        if (!MyContext)
        {
            MyContext.BeginInvoke(...);
            return; //Calling thread returns
        }
        else
        {
            UnsafeList.Add(someOtherArg);
            return; //MyContext Thread returns
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public foo()
    {
        MyContext = new GetSomeThreadHandle();
    }
}
```

I think I have an idea of how to do this with custom EventArgs, but it involves nearly repetitive code and I was looking for a more generic/cleaner solution.

#### Edit

This is using C# .Net 4.0

Comment: It's not terribly clear what you're really trying to achieve. Can you just put tasks on the thread pool? Also, please indicate which version of .NET you're using.

Comment: Basically I want to queue or serialize an action from multiple workers without blocking the workers. Using WinForms .Net 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that:

- You're using .NET 4
- You mentioned *queuing* and *serializing* the requests...

... it sounds like you want a producer/consumer queue, via [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). Start one thread (a consumer) which will pull from the queue, and then just add to the queue from your worker threads.

You'll need to think about what you want to happen if the queue builds up to an unexpected/undesirable level. (You could block, you could throw an exception, you could drop the requests.)

EDIT: For more information, see [this MSDN blog post on `BlockingCollection<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx).

Comment: This example demonstrate this way http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet hmm... briefly read the MSDN, could I queue `Action` delegates? I was hoping not to need wrapper methods for each real method I wanted to call, but rather to contain it all in the same method like when calling GUI Controls.

Comment: working through the blog posts, but not sure if this has merit yet.

Comment: this looks more promising http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx trying to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @JoshW: But you said that you didn't *have* a control... so you don't have a UI thread to schedule work for. Yes, you could queue `Action` delegates - but you'd normally just queue the inputs for your processing task. To be honest, it's still really not very clear what you're doing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet you're right, I do have Controls and eventually this is for a control, but it's called via a static method rather than an event.  Anyways, I solved my problem simply by creating a static `this` property which I set OnLoad of the form and set to null OnClosing.  I then have an instance I can reference later in the static method to use the normal GUI InvokeRequired/BeginInvoke calls.  I may look into blocking collections in the future, but seemed overkill for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Little example that demonstrate producer/consumer way applied to the your task

```
public void produceConsume()
{
    var results = new BlockingCollection<double[]>();

    var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var data = new double[1024];
            results.Add(data);                    
        }

        results.CompleteAdding();
    });

    var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in results.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
           // put in chart
        }
    });

    producer.Wait();
}
```

Also you can use ConcurrentQueue if you need more one counsumer consume all data